# Суммирование с двумя условиями

Tags: google-spreadsheet

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно посчитать сумму.
Для примера сделал [отдельную табличку](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LRss6E9q5C1TNwFjd5kQ-36q3RDYxk_nLSW5xsCZFw4/edit#gid=0).

Если в Tаблице 2 проданный товар имеет статус "Успешно" и название этого товара принадлежит определенному диапазону ячеек в Таблице 1, то мы суммируем все и вносим в ячейку "Выручка 1".

Аналогичная схема и для ячейки "Выручка 2", разница лишь в диапазоне.

```
=SUMIFS(G3:G; H3:H; "Успешно"; F3:F; )
```

Я пользуюсь формулой SUMIFS, но не понимаю как сделать условие для проверки соответствия диапазону.

Answer (score 2):

В *Excel* работает формула массива:

```
=СУММ(СУММЕСЛИМН(G3:G1000;H3:H1000;"Успешно";F3:F1000;ТРАНСП(B4:B5)))
```

Google-таблицы такую не принимают...

Сделаем немного длиннее, но проще. См. Google-таблицу.

Столбец D - определяем принадлежность товара к Закупу:

```
=IF(LEFT(A3;5)="Закуп";A3;D2)
```

Столбец I - к какому Закупу относится "успешный" товар:

```
=IF(H3="Успешно";VLOOKUP(F3;B:D;3;0);"")
```

Выручка:

```
=SUMIF(I:I;D6;G:G)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ!